# PHP - action hook 'ninja_forms_daily_action'

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I am looking at the source code for Ninja forms plugin. There is an action hook scheduled to execute daily in the file activation.php(line:51), but I cannot find the implementation of the action itself. I am assuming there should be a function called ninja_forms_daily_action somewhere in the code, but I can't seem to find it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I would recommend contacting the plugin author with this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no associated function. The full code is the following:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'ninja_forms_daily_action' );
```

What this essentially translates to is:

> Schedule a hook called `ninja_forms_daily_action` to be executed by the WordPress actions core on a daily interval, starting now.

This has been added so that developers can hook into it with their own functions...but the Ninja Forms core doesn't make use of it.

Read more about `wp_schedule_event()` [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event).